# Failed to load resource angular2-cookie

Tags: angular, angular2-cookie

I am trying to add 'angular2-cookie' in the quick start of angular-2 using visual studio.

following https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

I have made the following changes so far.

```
npm install angular2-cookie --save

System.config
  map: 
   // other libraries
    'angular2-cookie': 'npm:angular2-cookie'

  packages:'angular2-cookie': {
  main: './core.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
  }

  app.component.ts

    import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';

    providers: [CookieService]

   constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService) {
    _cookieService.put("test.com", "testCookie");
    console.log(_cookieService.get('test.com'));
```

The app builds fine, but ends up with Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http ://localhost:56249/angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service(…)

What am I missing?

Complete Code

system.config:

```
 System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
  'angular2-cookie': 'npm:angular2-cookie'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-cookie': {
  main: './core.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}  });
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<h1>Quickstart for angular</h1><div> Hello there!</div>',
providers: [CookieService]

})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService) {
    _cookieService.put("test.com", "testCookie");
    console.log(_cookieService.get('test.com'));

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code works today. Seems rebuild, delete browser cache helped.